# Is there a text wrap function in the java standard library?

Tags: java

The Python standard lib comes with the module `textwrap` which provides a simple text wrapping functionality. Is there something comparable in the java standard library?

in Python it is something like this:

```
>>> t = "a really really long string with lots of characters"
>>> import textwrap
>>> textwrap.wrap(t, 20)
['a really really long', 'string with lots of', 'characters']
```

Comment: could you add an example of the feature in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not in the standard Java library, but there is in Apache Commons:

[WordUtils.wrap](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html)

Comment: This is now deprecated, and replaced by commons-text, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.String-int-